# One-line backup, compress, scp database file

Tags: linux, ssh, backup, cron, postgresql

I support a company with a remotely hosted web site.  They use PostgreSQL dbs.

I can't write scripts on the remote server, and I don't want to store any backup files on the remote server, but I can run cron jobs, and I have access to the remote server's SSH public key.  I set up a local linux host to accept the remote host's private key for authentication.

I need to make a one-line script to backup, compress, and scp the backup file to my local linux box synchronously.

If my local linux box was reachable via SSH at `mylinuxbox.foo.com` on port 122, and my database's name was `mydatabase`, what would this one-liner cron job command look like?

Comment: Can you access the database remotely?  If so might be easier to write a script on the local box to pull the data instead of trying to push it from the remote side.

Comment: There are some provisions for shell access, but I'd rather it be a push operation if I can swing it.

Comment: Have you read [the section of the Postgres manual dealing with backup and restore](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/backup.html)? If not, stop now and go read it. Then all you need to do is wrap those instruction sin a shell script and run it from `cron`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you're using ident authentication (or a .pgpass) for the database I'd probably do something like the following :

```
pg_dump -Udbuser -h127.0.0.1 mydatabase |gzip -c > mydatabase.backup.gz; scp -P 122 mydatabase.backup.gz user@mylinuxbox.foo.com:; rm -f mydatabase.backup.gz
```

Editing to add another option...

If it's really important to not have intermediate storage of the backup file you could modify the above to look more like this:

```
pg_dump -Udbuser -h127.0.0.1 mydatabase |gzip -c | ssh -p 122 user@mylinuxbox.foo.com "cat >mydatabase.backup.gz"
```